# TYPO3 10.4: Link to subpage of mounted page generates link with wrong domain

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Imagine the following site configuration with TYPO3 v10.4 and Introduction Package installed:

#### First Site (https://us.domain.com)

-- Page A
-- Page B
---- Page B.1
---- Page B.2
-- Page C

#### Second Site (https://eu.domain.com)

-- Page A
-- Page B (**mounted with all subpages** (!) from „First Site“)
-- Page C
-- Page D

Now imagine a link (t3://page?uid=xx) on „Page D“ of „Second Site“ pointing to „Page B.1“. TYPO3 is generating a link with the domain of the „First Site“, but I want it to point to the same domain if the linked page is mounted in the current site.

I noticed that if the link goes from B.1 to B.2 (if pages share a common ancestor in root line) it works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?